# How to cancel hghcharts default behavior of the browser?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

How to cancel hghcharts default behavior of the browser?
such as scrolling?
Because when I test my web app on my mobile device, and highcharts will prevent scroll behavior....this experience is very bad, and I saw the API documentations, it makes me dizzy, but did not find a solution.....

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  How does Highcharts prevent your page from scrolling?

Comment: When I touch the screen with my finger, and I want to scroll down the page, but when I touch highchart chart ,and the page will not scroll down,just stoped

Comment: You should have disabled [followTouchMove](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.tooltip.followTouchMove). The same applies for `chart.zoomType` and `chart.pinchType`.